# Should I read the instructions to Betrayal Legacy before the Prologue?

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill, betrayal-legacy

I'm starting a game of Betrayal Legacy next week.

Everyone playing has played Betrayal at House on the Hill and/or Baldur's Gate, though it's been some time (months - years). I've played a lot, but the last time was about a year ago.

I think it would be exciting to open the box together, but this should be second to having the game go smoothly.

Are the rules similar enough to the other Betrayal games, or short enough, that I don't have to read them ahead of time, or should I familiarize myself with them before we meet for the Prologue (and possibly Chapter 1, depending on time).

Comment: Could someone create a betrayal-legacy tag?

Comment: I've created tag.  couldn't use betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill-legacy as that exceeded character limits

Comment: "Betrayal Legacy" is the correct name of the game, so that was the right outcome in any case. :)

Comment: thats ok then :-)

Comment: Based on a review I read the other day (sorry, can't link it, hence why this is in comment), *read the instructions* before you do anything else.

Comment: The beginning of the rules also contains a "here's what is different from other Betrayal games" page. If you learn those things, and you've played Betrayal before, you will likely be good.

Comment: How is it possible that I never knew about Betrayal Legacy before now??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gameplay is just different enough from the original game (example in spoilers below) to make reading the instructions necessary, but I think this can be done during unboxing with the other players. If you would prefer to read the instructions ahead of time but still open the box together, they're posted online at Avalon Hill's website: https://media.wizards.com/2018/downloads/rules/BLY-Rulebook.pdf

As noted by @bwarner "The beginning of the rules also contains a "here's what is different from other Betrayal games" page. If you learn those things, and you've played Betrayal before, you will likely be good."  This is page 3 of the rulebook linked above.

For the most part the Legacy deck will guide you through what's special about each chapter. Please note though that the rulebook itself will change during the course of the game, and should be reviewed during each session to re-familiarize yourselves with what's changed.

Gameplay spoilers (not anything plot related):

> Events / Item cards, similar to tiles, can now only be drawn in certain zones. e.g. There are "upstairs" items and "ground floor" items. This was hard to remember in our first game.

Rulebook comment (contains plot spoiler):

> During the prologue you may encounter a rule in-game related to something in the rulebook that doesn't have a reference icon. Note: the item referenced already exists in the house tiles. If it's unclear, try to look up what the icon should be.